# "expected pseudo-register; found R13" error

Tags: go

I just run a go project with goland and got error as blow:

```sh
# github.com/choleraehyq/pid
../../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10/pid_go1.5_amd64.s:28: expected pseudo-register; found R13
../../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10/pid_go1.5_amd64.s:29: expected pseudo-register; found R14
asm: assembly of ../../../.go/pkg/mod/github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10/pid_go1.5_amd64.s failed
```

I'm confused about this error and I don't know what todo. I can't do some debug work by this error message and didn't get any useful informations from google. `github.com/choleraehyq/pid` is referred by under framework.

I just want to know what happened and how to fix it. Please help me, thank you every much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to know what happened and how to fix it.

---

1. Read the instructions.

[Stack Overflow: Help: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

2. Follow the instructions.

---

For example,

package goid
[github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10)
Programatically retrieve the current goroutine's ID.

.

```
$ cat pid.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    goid "github.com/choleraehyq/pid"
)

func main() {
    pid := goid.GetPid()
    fmt.Println(pid)
}
$
```

.

```
$ cat go.mod
module example/pid

go 1.17

require github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.10
$
```

.

```
$ go version
go version go1.17.5 linux/amd64
$
```

.

```
$ go build pid.go && ./pid
# github.com/choleraehyq/pid
../../gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10/pid_go1.5_amd64.s:28: expected pseudo-register; found R13
../../gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10/pid_go1.5_amd64.s:29: expected pseudo-register; found R14
asm: assembly of ../../gopath/pkg/mod/github.com/choleraehyq/pid@v0.0.10/pid_go1.5_amd64.s failed
$
```

---

Upgrade to the latest version.

.

```
$ go get -u github.com/choleraehyq/pid
go: downloading github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.13
go: upgraded github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.10 => v0.0.13
$
```

.

```
$ cat go.mod
module example/pid

go 1.17

require github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.13
$
```

.

```
$ go build pid.go && ./pid
1
$
```

---

Avoid using old, obsolete, and unsupported versions of software.

---

---

UPDATE:

Comment from OP:

Thanks. The original project is a big project and has deep dependencies. I find that I need to add `github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.13 // indirect` to the project's `go.mod`. – sh1yu

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact the original project is a big project and has deeply dependencies. Firstly I don't know how to upgrade the dependencies' version, eventually I find that it just need add `github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.13 // indirect` to the project's go.mod.

Comment: @rocka2q Most of your answer isn't an actual answer. It would be best if you removed the "lesson" and kept the answer to the actual answer. Lessons can be taught in comments on the OP

Comment: @Cjmarkham: Stack Overflow comments are transient. Adding the OP's comment leaves the ultimate solution in the answer for future readers. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is a collection of useful, searchable Q&As.

Comment: I don't see how a comment is more transient than an answer...

Comment: @Cjmarkham: THe OP asked " know what happened and how to fix it." I explained how I discovered the problem: "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." Stack Overflow is a site for learning.

Comment: That is not what my last comment was about.....but okay.

Comment: @Cjmarkham: "Comments are disposable: unlike posts, there's no public revision history, and they can be deleted without warning by their authors, by moderators, and in response to flags." [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757)

Answer (score 1):

My go version is 1.17.6, also with this problem.

I solve the problem by updating the package version:

```
go get -u github.com/choleraehyq/pid
go get: upgraded github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.10 => v0.0.13
```

Answer (score 1):

It happened when I update go version from 1.13 -> 1.19
and I solve the problem by updating the package version:

```
go get -u github.com/choleraehyq/pid
go: downloading github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.15
go: upgraded github.com/choleraehyq/pid v0.0.13 => v0.0.15
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too. It maybe related to your golang's version;
I changed my golang's version from `1.17` to `1.14`, which solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Use go `1.16` instead of `1.17` also solved this problem for me.